# pl sql. 0 rows merged

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I am new to `merge` so this question may appear too dumb.

I'm running

```
MERGE INTO regions r
   USING regions_temp t
   ON (r.id_region = t.id_region)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (r.id_region, r.region_name)
     VALUES (t.id_region, t.region_name);
```

Before I run the command the tables have following records (id_region, region_name):

Regions:

```
1   1   Kiev
2   2   Asia
3   3   Australia
4   4   South America
5   5   Africa
```

Regions_temp:

```
1   1   
2   2   Asia
3   3   Australia
4   4   South America
```

The command runs successfully but on the bottom of the window it says **0 rows merged** and no records are merged.

Little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO regions r
   USING regions_temp t
   ON (r.id_region = t.id_region)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN update  set r.region_name =  t.region_name
```

is what i actually needed

Answer (score 0):

According to the [merge_insert_clause documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F__BGBGIICE):

> The merge_insert_clause specifies values to insert into the column of the target table if the condition of the ON clause is false.

Since there aren't records in `Regions_temp` whose `id_region` doesn't match a record in `Regions`, there are no rows to be merged.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @AjayTakur I've updated the link to the Oracle 19 docs

Comment: It's working now.